# Multilingual menus: logic and architecture

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

A question dedicated for developers: What is the right **Multi-lingual** option for entities and menus in Drupal 8? In contrast to Drupal 7 that never asked me for a menu language, some entities and menus in Drupal 8 asks me for a default... But... I don't want a singular language for that menu... I want it to include 2 and even 3 languages... Thus what is the logical option? My question is basically comprised of two questions:

1. Is it **Not specified**? Or **Not applicable**?, and what is the difference between the two?
2. I also wonder why the ready-to-work menus that comes with the Drupal 8 installation, are not multilingual and are locked to the language in which the site was installed... Won't it be more flexible to set it to some kind of a multilingual option and that's it?...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossibe to have one multilingual custom menu in Drupal 8.0.

What you have to do is to create one menu per language. You specify the one language of the menu as you show in your image.

Then in blocks you place all your menus in the same place. Here you can choose which menu is chosen for which language.

This is far from elegant, since you have to edit each language separately without a translate button. But apart from being a cluttered process to create, it works nicely.